# How to getRepository() for entity in subfolder with symfony 5.4?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

Prior to Symfony 5.4 I used to reference my entities like this

```
public function findAction($archived = false)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $analyses = $em->getRepository('App:Hazardlog\Analysis')->findAll();
```

I remember there was a new syntax for it ending with ::class a while back (possibly already in symfony 4) but I've been hanging on to this syntax because I have my entities organized into subfolders (a remnant from the old days when code in src was supposed to reside in a bunch of bundles...).

However, now all I get is a neat error saying

> Class 'Analysis::class' does not exist

This is my directory structure

```
Entity
  Hazardlog
    Analysis
    Risk
```

Now, I have tried a number of ways to reference my entities with the ::class at the end, but none seem to work.

Can I simply not keep my directories in symfony 5.4 or is there a way of doing it that I just didn't find?

I've tried

```
$analyses = $em->getRepository('App:Hazardlog\Analysis::class')->findAll();
```

Also tried

```
$analyses = $em->getRepository('Hazardlog\Analysis::class')->findAll();
```

As well as

```
$analyses = $em->getRepository('Analysis::class')->findAll();
```

(last one was a longshot I know, but since there is only one Analysis entity in the app, and symfony is set on a new syntax, I thought maybe symfony would be smart enough to find it anyways )

Any hints for me here?

------------------ UPDATE ---------------

From Cerad's comment I learned a few more ways that won't work

```
$analyses = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\Hazardlog\Analysis::class')->findAll();

$analyses = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\Hazardlog\Analysis\Analysis::class')->findAll();
```

And the way that actually works is

```
$analyses = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\Hazardlog\Analysis')->findAll();
```

Though I'm not sure if it's a bad idea to go with that, or if I should start referencing it with that "::class" appendage. What difference does it make?

Comment: "no need to change" you said but all I currently get is "Class 'Analysis::class' does not exist" so I would say changing at least something is necessary =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclosing a bunch of characters in single quotes (`'`) makes it a **string**. Therefore `'App\Entity\Hazardlog\Analysis::class'` is a string. And that string is *invalid* as an argument to the `getRepository` method because it is not a valid classname. Therefore you need to use `->getRepository('App\Entity\Hazardlog\Analysis')` instead - as *that* is the valid fully-qualified classname.

Instead, using `Analysis::class` (notice, no quotes). Is a shortcut in php to create the valid fully-qualified classname for the class. So, you *could* use `->getRepository(Analysis::class)` (again, no quotes) and php will convert the value. You will also notice in this case, that you must import the class - so up at the top of your class, you will have something like `import App\Entity\Hazardlog\Analysis;`. Without the import the `::class` trick doesn't do its job.

In the end, they are functionally the same. It is your preference which to use.